# How to get controls value without a submit in razor?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

There is a input :`<input type="text" asp-for="Model.Keywords" />`

and a Button :`<button asp-page-handler="Page" ></button>`

how to get the `input` value by click the `button`?

I know if I put the input in a form and submit it I can get the value.

But if I do not do this can I get it too?

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the value on the server side?

Comment: @itminus yes but without a submit to the server

Comment: Ok, before I write codes I still need confirm : do you want to send the value by ajax without a `<form/>` element?

Comment: @itminus thank you very much . I do not want to use ajax but only use asp-page-handler to send the value

Comment: If you mean to click the button on client side and get a value on server side automatically without javascript or `<form/>`, that's not impossible. You have to send a HTTP request so that the server side page handler will know it.

Comment: <button asp-page-handler="Page" asp-route-index="1"></button> when I click the button I will get a parameter of index=1 but if I do not specify the asp-route-index Can I get a value which is a input type="text"?

Comment: Actually, your above code won't make you get a index=1 when clicking the button unless you have a handler to process it.  Maybe you want to use a `<a href=...>` to sent a `GET` request.

Comment: yes I have a handler to process it .but even I have the handler I still can not get the value if I do not send the request

Comment: In order to make the server side knows the input value,  you have to send a HTTP request to the server either by `<form>`/`<a>`/ ... element or by `javascript` when  clicking the button.  I'm not sure what you want to do. But according to your description, you don't want a `<form>`/ `<a>` element, and you don't want to use ajax too. IMHO, it's impossible.